# How to implement Tensorflow serving with secured channels

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, grpc, tensorflow-serving

I have currently created a tensorflow serving model which predicts whether the given image is a cat or dog. In my tensorflow serving client script, I have used the insecure channel for communication,

```
host, port = hostport.split(':')
channel = implementations.insecure_channel(host, int(port))
```

I want to use the secure channel(SSL/TLS) for communication. I looked into the site https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/193 where they use

```
host, port = FLAGS.server.split(':')
creds = grpc.ssl_channel_credentials(open('roots.pem').read())
```

Over here I am not able to understand what is roots.pem and how do I create one for my tensorflow serving model. Please let me know how to implement tensorflow serving with SSL/TSL(secured channel)

Error when passing no parameters to the ssl_channel_credentials() function, creds = grpc.ssl_channel_credentials()

```
E0403 13:59:04.799573344   23914 ssl_transport_security.cc:989] Handshake 
failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:100000f7:SSL 
routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER.
E0403 13:59:04.800359343   23922 ssl_transport_security.cc:989] Handshake 
failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:100000f7:SSL 
routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Client.py", line 85, in <module>
tf.app.run()
File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site- 
packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 124, in run
_sys.exit(main(argv))
File "Client.py", line 76, in main
result = stub.Predict(request, 60.0)
File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site- 
packages/grpc/beta/_client_adaptations.py", line 309, in __call__
self._request_serializer, self._response_deserializer)
File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site- 
packages/grpc/beta/_client_adaptations.py", line 195, in 
_blocking_unary_unary
raise _abortion_error(rpc_error_call)
grpc.framework.interfaces.face.face.AbortionError: 
AbortionError(code=StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE, details="Connect Failed")
```

Comment: Note that [the `root_certificates` parameter to `grpc.ssl_channel_credentials` is optional](https://grpc.io/grpc/python/grpc.html#grpc.ssl_channel_credentials). If you don't know what a `roots.pem` is... don't pressure yourself to provide one? What happens if you just create your credentials with `channel_credentials = grpc.ssl_channel_credentials()`?

Comment: Hi @NathanielManistaAtGoogle. Thanks for your response. I tried creating credentials with channel_credentials = grpc.ssl_channel_credentials(). It resulted in a Handshake failed error. I have pasted the error message in my question above. Please look into it. Thank you

Comment: Well... "Connect Failed" is at least probably not security-related, so that's something. With what version of `grpcio` are you working, and to what server are you trying to connect?

Comment: @NathanielManistaAtGoogle Thanks for your reply. grpcio version is 1.10. I am trying to connect it to tensorflow model server present in the docker.

Comment: Finally I was able to figure it out. We need to change the tensorflow serving code or the model server to support SSL.

Comment: This issue was addressed [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/193) and please go through it, let us know if this helps.

Comment: @ReInvent_IO what did you change in the serving code for the secure channel to work?